# Not Able To Read A Form Data Using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have made a form inside `index.html`, which contains following the form:

```html
<form action="/row_selection_form" action="POST" id="Row_Selection_Form">
            <div class="float-right ">Show Rows <select class="custom-select-sm form-control-sm m-1" id="select-rows" onchange="submit_form()" name="select">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option></select>
            <input value="Sam" name="sam">
             </div>
             </form>
```

Here is how the JavaScript function named `submit_form()` inside `index.html` looks like:

```js
function submit_form(){

            document.getElementById("Row_Selection_Form").submit();

          }
```

And here is how my flask function in order to handle this POST request looks like

```py
@app.route("/row_selection_form", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def doing_pagination():

    print("Form has got submitted, running doing_pagination()")
    name = request.form["select"]
    print("GOt the name ", name)

    return redirect(url_for("start_application"))
```

But I can't understand why after the form mentioned above gets submitted, I get the following output

```
Form has got submitted, running doing_pagination()
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2021 21:22:58] "GET /row_selection_form?select=25&sam=Sam HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "D:\VS Code Workspace\Fair Space\Devlopment\VPC_Clinic\Code\Main_Code.py", line 435, in doing_pagination
    name = request.form["select"]
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 377, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'select'
```

Can anybody kindly help me to overcome this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML Form method = POST (instead of action). Also in flask, try the id of the select (select-rows). Something like: request.form.get("select-rows")

Comment: @S2L Thanks for helping me, now I get no error but receive the following output `Form has got submitted, running doing_pagination()
GOt the name  None`

Comment: Even though I selected one of the option, still I am unable to figure out why None can as the output

Comment: Actually, my mistake. Use the name of select attribute in flask to retrieve value. I will also post an example in answer.

Comment: @S2L Problem has got solved. I changed the name to `select-rows` and put `method=POST` as you suggested. Thanks for your help, I was stuck in this problem for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary to above comments:

1. Change html form action to method
2. For html select, use name attribute to retrieve value in flask.
3. In flask, use request.form.get("select")

HTML fragment.

```
<select id="select-rows" onchange="submit_form()" name="select">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/row_selection_form", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def doing_pagination():

    print("Form has got submitted, running doing_pagination()")
    name = request.form.get("select")
    print("GOt the name ", name)
    return name
    #return redirect(url_for("start_application"))

app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting such a useful answer